# asp:textbox text removed after whitespace when passed to C # Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, textbox, whitespace

I have a site where users can enter some singleline to a description field, with later on will be added to the work folder that's created.

My problem is that if the text they enter in the description field contains a whitespace, when i then call from .cs page it only takes the text from beginning to that whitespace. I want the whole value that the user types in.

ex: 
"This is a Description" Outcome: "This"

Default.ASPX Page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="SectionHeader">Beskrivning
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorDescription" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="TextBoxDescription" EnableClientScript="False" 
           onservervalidate="CustomValidatorDescription_ServerValidate" 
           ValidateEmptyText="True" ForeColor="#DD0000">
        </asp:CustomValidator>
      </span><br />
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDescription" runat="server" MaxLength="150" 
           Width="562px" CssClass="textinput" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
                                BorderWidth="0px" CausesValidation="False" 
                     ImageUrl="~/images/help_icon_off.png" CommandName="4" 
        oncommand="ImageButton_Command" ToolTip="Visa hjälp för fältet" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="tip" Visible="False">
            Är den (metadata) text som kommer att visas i uppdragskatalogen i filutforskaren 
            i Windows.<br />
    Denna information går att ändra i efterhand.
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I posted the whole thing from ASPX file incase you guys need to check out some other things that the .cs uses like "UpdatePanel4" or "CustomValidatorDescription"

Default.ASPX.CS :

```
 protected void ButtonCreateDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 string description = TextBoxDescription.Text;
```

Then i use "description" for what i need to do.
I also have 2 dropdown list and another text field which i pass to the .cs page which works fine, allthough there's no whitespaces on those fields.

Comment: Can't see anything immediately wrong in your aspx that would cause this. At this stage my main suspicion would fall on what the CustomValidator is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a pritty easy but tricky fix :)

The cs page triggers a powershell script located locally with the data that the user has filled in on the page. Since its whitespaces when you call a powershell script you need " between. This solved the issue:

```
string vartDescription = "'" + TextBoxDescription.Text + "'";
```

So it was the powershell script that was called "wrong". :)